# Yii framework: CMenu - get messages count

Tags: frameworks, yii

I am learning yii framework and i have problem. I have **CMenu:**

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
                array('label'=>'Messages ('. User::model()->with('messages_count')->find() .')', 'url'=>array('/message/index')),
                array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
            ),
        )); ?>
```

and **relation in User model:**

```
'messages_count' => array(self::STAT,'Message','owner_id'),
```

In site that shows me 'Messaages (admin)', but I expect 'Messages (3)', so I think this line is wrong:

```
User::model()->with('messages_count')->find()
```

But I don't know how to get only count. Can you help me?

P.s Is there possibility to add criteria to relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` finds a single active record with the specified condition.

`count()` finds the number of rows satisfying the specified query condition.

Your sollution:

```
User::model()->with('messages_count')->count();
```

With CDbCriteria:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->with = 'messages_count';
// your extra criteria 
User::model()->count($criteria);
```

Be sure to check out the Yii documentation especially if you're learning to work with Yii and CActiveRecord: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord